# Having difficulties with 2 simultaneous Vite dev servers & @vite blade directive. Is there a way to use 2 different ports with @vite in blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vite, inertiajs

I am running a freshly installed Laravel project (9.48) with Vite & Inertia, including the welcome view, authentication views & dashboard.

So far I have managed to separate all the assets for the frontend and backend environments

You could say I run two vite configs:

vite/app.config.js  on port 3000
vite/admin.config.js on port 3001

When I run ether 1 of them, the apps work fine. But as soon as I start up the second dev server, the problem starts:

The public/hot file gets overwritten with the new port, from `http://[::]:3000 to 3001`

Now the @vite blade directive uses port 3001 for both app & admin, causing the app the break:

`<script type="module" src="http://[::]:3001/@vite/client"></script><script type="module" src="http://[::]:3001/resources/assets/app/entry.js"></script>`

In case I start up the admin dev server first & the app second, the problem works the other way around.

Is there a way to use 2 different ports with 2 simultaneous Vite dev servers & the @vite helper in blade?

Also I am not sure if this was a good idea to begin with... But I'm attempting to implement Inertia for the usual websites I build, for both the Admin environment & the front-end. Just backend would make this a hell of a lot easier, but so far it's working (almost!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is still interested, in the vite config file, under the Laravel plugin, you can asign a different hot file.

```
plugins: [
    vue(),
    laravel({
        input: [
            'resources/admin/entry.js'
        ],
        port: 3001,
        refresh: true,
        hotFile: 'public/hot-admin',
        buildDirectory: 'build-admin',
    }),
]
```

Then under the boot method in your AppServiceProvider you can task the @vite blade helper to use a different hot file. You would have to wrap this in a check for the request being 'admin'

```
if ($requestIsAdmin) {
    Vite::useBuildDirectory('build-admin')
        ->useHotFile('hot-admin');
}
```

Now you can include the vite assets into your blade file like this while running the 2 vite dev servers simultaneously. Depending on your request, a different hotfile will be used.

```
@vite(['resources/admin/js/entry.js'])
```

Comment: Finally! I searched and searched, got errors all over the place (confusing resolving errors, mixing up frontend and backend app sources) Now it works like a charm, thank you!